# Unable to create team from group

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have been trying to create a team from group using the graph api.However I keep getting errors.
I have tried a couple of variations.

Variation 1

```
    Map<String,JsonElement> additionalData = new HashMap<String, JsonElement>();
        additionalData.put("group@odata.bind", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('902e46a0-471f-4e41-9c33-77abae63245d')"));
        additionalData.put("template@odata.bind", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')"));
       team.additionalDataManager().putAll(additionalData);

       HeaderOption option = new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.accessToken());
       ITeamCollectionRequest res = graphClient.teams().buildRequest(Arrays.asList(option));
       res.post(team);
```

Variation 2

```
    Map<String,JsonElement> additionalData = new HashMap<String, JsonElement>();
    additionalData.put("template@odata.bind", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')"));
    HeaderOption option = new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.accessToken());
    ITeamRequest req = graphClient.groups("902e46a0-471f-4e41-9c33-77abae63245d").team().buildRequest(Arrays.asList(option));       
        req.post(team);
```

In both variations I end up with errors such as 502 Bad Gateway Unable to execute backend request or 404 NOT FOUND Unknown error.

I am using graph sdk - 1.7.1 with java.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing two things:

- Upgrading a group to a team -> this doesn't accept a template and is done with a PUT request.
- Creating a team, with a template -> this doesn't accept a group and is done with a POST request.

First option should look like this:

```
HeaderOption option = new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.accessToken());
ITeamRequest req = graphClient.groups("902e46a0-471f-4e41-9c33-77abae63245d").team().buildRequest(Arrays.asList(option));       
    req.put();
```

Second option should look like this:

```
Map<String,JsonElement> additionalData = new HashMap<String, JsonElement>();
additionalData.put("template@odata.bind", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')"));
team.additionalDataManager().putAll(additionalData);
HeaderOption option = new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.accessToken());
ITeamRequest req = graphClient.teams().buildRequest(Arrays.asList(option));       
    req.post(team);
```

Comment: there is no put method available...only patch method is available. can u specify which sdk version are you using

Comment: you are correct, the method is missing from the SDK: Here is a workaround
String url = String.format("/groups/%s/team", groupID);
Team createdTeam = graphClient.customRequest(url, Team.class).buildRequest().put(team);